# Making a dynamic table name in python mySQLdb

Tags: python

i'm trying to write a program where i loop through a list of strings and use those strings to make names for my tables, however i don't quite understand how to properly escape everything without getting an error.
Heres my code right now:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s' %data[1])

0L

sql ="""CREATE TABLE %s  (IP TEXT, AVAILIBILITY INT)""" %data[1]
cursor.execute(sql)
0L

for key in data[0]:

    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s,%s)""" %(data[1],key,data[0][key]))
    db.commit()


1L
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM %s""" %data[1])
1L
print cursor.fetchall()
((188L, 90),) 
db.close()
```

My code works when i enter a string rather than a variable that represents a string, but fails when using a variable

Answer (score 0):

you should use string formatting in this line

`sql ="""CREATE TABLE data[1]  (IP TEXT, AVAILIBILITY INT, AP TEXT )"""`

when you call cur.execute(sql) method on it, this will raise errorclass or/and errorvalue error.

try something like this:

`sql ="""CREATE TABLE %s  (IP TEXT, AVAILIBILITY INT, AP TEXT )""" %data[1]`

Comment: Thanks, that worked for that line and the one after, however now i get an error here that says "not enough arguments for format string"                                                                       cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""" %data[1], (key,item[key],data[1]))

Comment: `sql = """INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""" %(data[1], key,item[key],data[1])`

for multiple strings formatting, use `%(var1, var2, var3, var4 ...)`

also have a look up here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: Thanks, that didn't quite fix it i get "string indices must be integer not str" now but i can probably take it from here

Comment: maybe you have problem with your `dictionary`. can you share a piece from your `item` dictionary and `data` list?

Comment: its just strings mapped to either 0's 1's or 2's ({'10.32.20.158': 1, '10.32.20.159': 1, '10.32.20.150': 1, '10.32.20.151': 1, '10.32.20.152': 1, '10.32.20.153': 1, '10.32.20.154': 1, '10.32.20.155': 1, '10.32.20.156': 1, '10.32.20.157': 1, '10.32.20.215': 1, '10.32.20.253': 1, '10.32.20.252': 1, '10.32.20.251': 1

Comment: nevermind, found it. no errors now but nothing is actaully posting to my database

Comment: if you are iterating over this data (hope there is no opening paranthesis symbol in your actual code),

`for item in data:` will assign ip numbers (str) to item variable in every loop. in second iteration `for key in item[0]`, key will take values of 0th element of ip string (e.g. `'10.32.20.158'[0]`=`1`). 

check your code seperately if  `key`, `item[0][key]`, and `item[1]` takes the values you want.

Comment: Yeah, i changed it to this, and now no errors its just not posting
 for key in data[0]:

  sql = """INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s,%s)""" %(data[1],key,data[0][key])

Comment: let me notice, your keys are not integer, but `availibility` field in table should take integer values.

Comment: I changed the code in the question to what i have now, but im still getting an SQL syntax error, any ideas?